# Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in filecopy.exe

Tags: c, visual-studio, crt

It's the simpliest program but I've got this error. I copy all information from one file to another. (Frankly I need to copy information from several files)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 void CopyTo(FILE *x)
 {
    FILE *f0;
    char *s=new char[100];
    f0=fopen("file0.txt","wt+");
    while(fgets(s,sizeof(s),x))
    {
        fwrite(s,1,strlen(s)+1,x);
    }
    fclose(f0);    
 };

 int main()
 {
    FILE *fi;
    fi=fopen("file1.txt","rt");
    CopyTo(fi);
    fclose(fi);
    printf("finish");
    getchar();
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding error handling to your code?  You don't check the return values of any of the library functions.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't call `CopyFile` from Win32.

Comment: And if you have to do it yourself, pair `fwrite` with `fread`. A verbatim file copy should not worry at all about zero terminators etc.

Comment: I don't use CopyFile because I need to append to file0.txt information from another files

Comment: OK then. But use `fread` rather than `fgets`. And use a bigger buffer, 100 bytes at a time is on the low side. And please don't leak the buffer!

Comment: there are only simple phrases in all files.like `abcdef` or `qwerty`

Comment: I don't see the relevance of that comment.

Comment: it seems that I've translated `100 bytes at a time is on the low side` incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@a1ex07 has addressed some of the issues with your current code. However, as I stated in comments, I think your code could be implemented more effectively with some more significant changes.

I believe you have the following problems:

1. You are allocating a buffer on the heap and failing to free it.
2. Your buffer is rather small. It would likely be more efficient to use a larger buffer.
3. The use of `fgets` and `strlen`, C string oriented functions is inappropriate for what is a byte-by-byte copy operation.

I would write it like this:

```
void CopyTo(FILE *x)
{
    FILE *f0;
    char buff[16*1024];//16kB buffer, stack allocated
    size_t count;

    f0=fopen("file0.txt", "wt+");
    do
    {
        count = fread(&buff, 1, sizeof(buff), x);
        if (!ferror(x))
        {
            fwrite(&buff, 1, count, f0);
        }
    } while (count == sizeof(buff));
    fclose(f0);    
};
```

Note that this function has no error checking. Neither did yours. I'll leave it to you to add that if you wish. Also, I've only compiled this in my head. If there are any glitches I'm sure you can sort them out.

Comment: I think it would be better to rewrite it in c++ with fstream and etc.

Comment: That would make life easier. Then you'd get error handling through exceptions.

Comment: Hm...Either to read atricles about streams in C++(I don't know how to work with files in C++. I know only how to work with it in C#)  or just write whole program in another compiler.

Comment: Well, I can't see what's wrong with the MS compiler. Really should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to read from and write to the same file (x). Shouldn't it be 
`fwrite(s,1,strlen(s),f0)` ?
**UPDATE**
Also , I believe it should be 
`while(fgets(s,100,x))`, because `sizeof(s)` returns size of (`char*`)

Comment: However it doesn't solve the problem. It fails on `while(fgets...))`

Comment: @David Heffernan : you are right. fixing; I just copied it from the question.

Comment: I have tried another compiler(C-free 4) and it seems to work correctly. Sth with visual studio

Comment: Changing compiler is an implausible solution!